# Where to Download 5.13.7 ESR

Tags: civimember, developer, release, esr

Where/how do I get the tarball for CiviCRM 5.13.7 ESR Drupal 7 edition.

I have two different $20/month membership subscriptions to CiviCRM. Logged in to my civicrm.org  account I have twice filled out a form asking for my email address and User name.

I see nothing in my email and no messages on my account page.

How do I get it?

Comment: Sorry to hear that - I’ve pinged Josh (who adminsters this) on ESR channel in Mattermost referencing your post

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for supporting CiviCRM! You can use [this ESR form for members](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/create?gid=137&reset=1) to request a download key.

There is more information in the FAQ on the [ESR page](https://civicrm.org/esr).

When we launched Extended Security Releases (ESR) as a service, we were not sure how many people would sign up, so we started handling the requests manually. It seems like it's here to stay, so we are currently working on automating the process.

Comment: I had visited the page referred to in this answer several times and filled out the form referred to in this answer twice, with no results, before posting this question. I still have not heard from Josh as of this writing.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! (and for responding late). If you are still having issues, please email me at mathieu@civicrm.org. We are in the process of fully automating this.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to the ESR Releases is:

https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases