# 2 Questions: Where to download CiviCRM for wordpress v5.45 ESR? Triggers Required?

Tags: wordpress, trigger, esr, shared-hosting

Shared LAMP hosting • WordPress 6.0.1 • Using CiviCRM for over a decade on Dreamhost • Current CiviCRM version: 5.38.0

**First Question:**

I'd like the ESR 5.45, as recommended, but when I go to this page,

https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases

as suggested here:

[Where to Download 5.13.7 ESR](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33892/where-to-download-5-13-7-esr/33904#33904)

or even if I log with a CiviCRM account in and click the link to the same destination, I get a 404.

I know thinking of CiviCRM as a WordPress plugin is a bit like the tail wagging the dog, but is it possible there might just be a list of releases like they do with WordPress, easily accessible and zipped for download for WordPress and other CMS users without having to use Git? Including the ESR versions? Because documentation suggests such a page existed once... Why was it removed? (Okay that's a third, ancillary question.)

**Second Question:**

When I try to install CiviCRM 5.52.0, I get this response:

> CiviCRM 5.52.0 requires MySQL trigger privileges

Dreamhost shared hosting doesn't allow triggers. So I reinstalled the old CiviCRM 5.38.

If the ESR 5.45 requires triggers, we'll need to try a different hosting situation. Shoestring budget here... I've been keeping this updated since 2006. Does the latest ESR (5.45.7) require triggers? Version 5.38.0 apparently doesn't. If so, I'll need to look at more advanced MySQL hosting options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A couple clarifications: That trigger message has been there for years - did something change at dreamhost? For ESR, maybe you already know but you have to log in to civicrm.org using an account that has paid for ESR, otherwise you will get a 404. For git, I'm not sure what you mean - the civicrm wordpress download is a zip file, e.g. https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.52.1-wordpress.zip

Comment: Thanks for your reply. | Yes, apparently dreamhost used to allow triggers. Any existing triggers may stay. However new triggers are apparently now disallowed on shared hosting. Yes, I've logged in on CiviCRM.org to get the file. Except it still says it's 404 when I get to the crucial link. | There is no obvious page at civicrm.org that includes all previous versions of WordPress zips for CiviCRM. At least I couldn't find it. 5.52.1 will not install because of the trigger thing.

Comment: There's an archive of downloads at https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable. For ESR, if you're sure the account you're logging in with has paid the ESR fee for access, then you could try either emailing info@civicrm.org or contact Josh in https://chat.civicrm.org.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of a fee for access to ESR. I just created an account.

Comment: Sign up for ESR here: https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=64, but NOTE: 5.45 is 6 months old - the next ESR will be 5.51, and then you will have the same trigger problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same trigger problem with the 5.45 update. Just tried. Obviously dreamhost yanked a privilege. I understand why ESR might be a subscriber paid service, but unfortunately our 501c3 isn't in the position to pay. So... Looking into other options. I truly appreciate your help in this!

Comment: 2006 is impressive. any reason to go for ESR rather than standard release?

Comment: Yeah, 2006! I was hoping the latest ESR was close enough to my current version that it wouldn't add new triggers. It did. Apparently upgrading to MySQL 8 has changed how privileges are managed on shared hosting for Dreamhost. MySQL VPS is out of our budget. So I'm looking at transferring to an alternative free CRM for this non-profit.

Comment: Standard Civi is free, it's just the extended support aspect that isn't. Why not switch to other hosting that supports Civi?  eg civihosting.com

Comment: @Aidan, Civihosting costs about the same as adding MySQL VPS at even the lowest price level, and we're pretty dug in at the free hosting available for non-profits on Dreamhost. I'm talking with a specialist at TechSoup to learn more no-cost options. If there is an option I've missed, please let me know. Thanks!